# What is a "dimension counting argument"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've read a few proofs that use the phrase, "by a dimension counting argument" such and such is true. What does this mean? [Here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mnica/hermitian2014.pdf) is an example (Proof of Lemma 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means an argument based on counting the dimension of vector sub-spaces, using the relation

$\dim(U+W) + \dim(U \cap W) = \dim(U) + \dim(W)$

where $U$ and $W$ are sub-spaces of a vector space $V$. If $V$ has dimension $n$ then $\dim(U+W) \le n$ so

$\dim(U \cap W) \ge \dim(U) + \dim(W) - n$

In the proof of Lemm2, $S_k$ has dimension $k$ and $\text{span} \{ v_k, \dots, v_n \}$ has dimension $n-k+1$, so

$\dim(S_k \cap \text{span} \{v_k, \dots, v_n \}) \ge k + (n-k+1) - n$

$\Rightarrow \dim(S_k \cap \text{span} \{v_k, \dots, v_n \}) \ge 1$

and so $S_k \cap \text{span} \{v_k, \dots, v_n \}$ must contain a non-zero vector.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that in $\Bbb R^n$ two subspaces with dimensions that sum to more than $n$ must have an intersection greater than the origin.  As an example, two planes in $\Bbb R^3$ that pass through the origin must intersect in at least a line.  In $\Bbb R^n$ if you have subspaces of dimensions $k$ and $m$ the intersection must have dimension at least $k+m-n$